# MP4 videos hosted on Internet cannot be dowloaded and played on Android OS When size bigger than 1,7MB

Tags: android, video-streaming, mp4

I have hosted some videos for Mobile-Learning on Internet (for direct or progressive download, not video streaming service) and I want them to be playable in most of the mobile devices, especially the ones with Android 1.6 and higher.

The video container is MP4 with H264/AVC and AAC LC which is compatible with Symbian, Android, Windows Mobile and iPhone/IPad.

I have checked the videos with SonyEricsson X10 and Samsung (both of them, Android 1.6 based) and you get an error when the videos have a size higher than 1,7 MB. You can't either download or play them.

However, if I save the videos on the SD cards using the USB connection, they work regardless of the file size.

The same videos in the same server work perfectly using SonyEricsson Symbian based, HTC Windows Mobile based and iPhone and iPad.

I saw some posts for this situation but not solved. Has anyone found out the reason of this and the solution? For me it is vital that the videos mp4 and located on the Internet and played automatically, progressive streamed or when downloaded.

Thank you for your help!!

Answer (score 3):

To be able to use progressive playback on Android, the mp4 video needs to be hinted.
On Ubuntu 10.10 use following commands to encode and hint the video:

```
source=source.avi
ffmpeg -t 600 -i $source -acodec libfaac -ab 128k -ac 2 -vcodec libx264 \
  -vpre hq -crf 22 -threads 0 tmp.mp4 && \
/usr/bin/MP4Box -3gp -mtu 1450 -hint tmp.mp4 -out target.mp4
```

For a working example you can try the following snippet: http://212.179.137.52/office_progressive.mp4